# Am facing this error before starting the application?

Tags: spring-boot

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-12 18:47:51.811 ERROR 340 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field leadRepository in com.example.lead.controller.LeadController required a bean of type 'com.example.lead.repo.LeadRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.lead.repo.LeadRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: show code of controller and repository

Comment: can you show the class `com.example.lead.repo.LeadRepository` (entire code, with annotations ) also do you have `@ComponentScan` annotation to the main app class?

Comment: i have mentioned everything as you have mentioned above. but am not able to start the application. i am facing the error <terminated>. but i have no idea why is that occuring.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.lead.repo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
// import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import com.example.leadmodel.Lead;
import com.example.leadmodel.LeadEntity;


@Repository 
public interface LeadRepository extends JpaRepository<Lead, Integer> {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    Lead findOne(Integer lead_id);

    void save(LeadEntity leadEntity);

}
```